# Stash the Value of edittext into an variable and print it into LogCat

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, gettext

I am new to Android Development and Java. I have problems stashing the value of an EditText into a variable and printing it out in the Console afterwards.
I have read about getText(), but i dont quite understand how it works.
Here is my script:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/simplenote_mainpage_background_200"
android:paddingBottom="0px"
android:paddingLeft="0px"
android:paddingRight="0px"
android:paddingTop="0px"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="Title.."
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:hint="Note.."
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>



</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
    public class notescreen extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notescreen);

    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    String value = text.getText().toString();



   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

I have tried some things you suggested, by i am getting a lot of problems:
I would like to upload a screenshot, but i dont have 10 reputations.
Here is the edited code:

```
package com.example.simplenote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class notescreen extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.notescreen);

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    EditText title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);

     b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

             String value = title.getText().toString();

            tv =settext(value);

                }
            });
     final String TAG = "MyClass";
             Log.d(TAG, value);
    //EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    //String value = text.getText().toString();



   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


  }
```

Comment: Your code looks correct from what I can tell, in what way is not working. Are any errors shown in the log cat

Comment: Yes but i am not sure wich is the variable, in wich my text ist stored. Second, the part wich prints the variable in the Console is missing. I dont know how i accomplish that.

Comment: Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Add your packagename here please

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class notescreen extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Here is where you call the super on this method.
        // Mostly always comes as first line of any onCreate.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // After you have your layout set, you can retrieve your references
        setContentView(R.layout.notescreen);

        // You have just recovered your view class
        final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);

        // You have just recovered the text of that view class (text)
        // final String value = text.getText().toString();

        // The log works as a printer on the console
        // Log.d("notescreen", "This is the text: " + value);

        // But hey... there is no text right "onCreate", right?
        // Soo...

        // Retrieve a button (you will need to create it on XML first)
        final Button clickForTextBt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickfortextbt);

        // Make that button print your message
        clickForTextBt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("notescreen", "This is the text: " + text.getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this i get 3 problems:
View cannot be resolved to a type,
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnclickListener(){}),
OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type.

How can i solve those?

Comment: If view cannot be resolved to a type, there may be something wrong on your project configurations. Can you please confirm that this is indeed a android project and if you are using eclipse you have the android plugin correctly installed?

Comment: Yes it is an android project and I think I've installed the plugin correctly. I donwloaded the adt bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Comment: AHHH, i forgot to import android.view.View; and android.view.View.OnClickListener;. reis_eliel solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class notescreen extends Activity {


//Its a good practice to declare all the things that you want in activity
String value;
Button b1;
TextView tv;
EditText title;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.notescreen);

// here you have to initialize by its id
b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);

 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

         value = title.getText().toString();

        tv.settext(value);

            }
        });


  }

}
```

Make an TextView in your xml file

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv"
android:layout_width="285dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 >
```

Comment: I tried this, but now i am getting a lot of problems:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable title inside an inner class defined in a different method,
View cannot be resolved to a type,
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnclickListener(){})
How can i solve those?

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, you do not which is the variable which is storing the value.

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
```

The line above, that is storing a reference to your `EditText`. This allows you to call functions on that object relevant to the EditText, i.e. `getText()` and `setText()`. There are other functions you can call as well but those two are the main two you are going to want to use.

`getText` retrieves the value from the text box, e.g. if you typed into the text box "hello" then `getText()` would return the string "hello". `getText()` will always return a string, even if a number has been entered.

`setText` sets the contents shown in the text box. E.g. if you were to run s `text.setText("hello");` when this line is executed it will show "hello" in the edit text.

```
String value = text.getText().toString();
```

The line above is where you are storing the actual value of the edit text. So, using the example above, you typed "hello" into the edit text, when the line above is called the variable `value` will now equal `"hello"`.

To output this variable to the console, there is a class called `Log`. This class has various functions that outputs to the console (otherwise known as logcat in android).

The various types are

Log.d = debug type messages
Log.e = messages to indicate error (coloured in red)
Log.v = verbose messages (coloured green)
Log.w = warning messages (coloured yellow)

I think there are a couple of others but I can't remember them.

To output your variable that has the value from what the text.getText() function returned you pass this variable into one of the above Log functions.

Each of the above log functions take two parameters, a `tag` parameter and a `value` parameter.

The tag parameter is just a name, so you can filter the messages to only show that name, it is quite common to create a static final string for the tag which is the class name, for example in the line below.

```
private static final string TAG = "MyClass"
```

Then to output the text variable you would use the following line

```
Log.d(TAG, value);
```

You could if you wanted to make the message clearer as to what that value represents, concat a string at the beginning so the could might become

```
Log.d(TAG, "The value of my edit text is: " + value);
```

Using the example above, if in your edit text you typed hello, the log cat would show one of the following, depending on what line you used above

```
MyClass       hello
MyClass       The value of my edit text is: hello
```

Hope this helps